# What is the weakest proof-theoretic system needed to define $\pi$?

Tags: ordinals

Can we define the constant $\pi$ in [systems weaker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) than ZF?  If so, what are the weakest systems powerful enough to define $\pi$?

Comment: Galactically weaker systems than $\mathsf{ZF}$ suffice to appropriately define (some circumlocutions may be required) and analyze $\pi$. Already first-order Peano arithmetic is massive overkill for all the "standard" facts about $\pi$ - e.g. its transcendentality - and I suspect that anything proved about $\pi$ in an undergraduate class can even be proved in the even weaker system $I\Sigma_2$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber this is interesting, since [Peano Arithmetic is not stronger than Euclidean Geometry](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/concern/graduate_thesis_or_dissertations/cr56n4434?locale=en).  This seems to imply to me that Euclidean Geometry is much stronger than necessary to define $\pi$.

Comment: That thesis treats **both** arithmetic and geometry as second-order theories (see e.g. axiom IV on page 33). I was very careful in my comment above to specify that *first-order* Peano arithmetic was meant. Note that ZFC itself is a first-order theory, despite "being about" sets.

Comment: The Euler product for $\pi$ may be formalizable in $I\Delta_0$+exp, which is weaker than Peano arithmetic. https://mathoverflow.net/a/21389